# Nothing happens when setting the background of JScrollPane.getViewPort()

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a `JPanel` with layout set to null and the background is white. Then I added that `JPanel` to `JScrollPane`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TestJScollPane extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestJScollPane() {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI()
    {
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        scrollPane.setBounds(1, 1, 200, 200);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED); 
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA));
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLayout(null);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(this);
        frame.add(scrollPane);

        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

        return new Dimension(30,30);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TestJScollPane();
    }
}
```

My scenario is I have a zoom tool that if I zoom out the `JPanel` and all its shapes that were painted were scaled using `AffineTransform`. So I expect that if I zoom out, the background of `JScrollPane` was color gray but the actual was color white.

Apologies, I added a sample. Actually, this is not the actual code I created this so that I can provide a sample for you guys to help me.

I set the preferred size of `JPanel` to 30x30 so I expect that the background of `JScrollPane` will become visible but it was not.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). *A combo of scroll pane & `null` layout typically ends in grief.*

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Please see my added example.

Comment: @wildpeanut, don't forget to "accept" an answer, by clicking on a checkmark, so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: @camickr, I cannot accept answers from both of you guys. How can I do that? For now I am going to accept Mr. camickr's answer.

Comment: Each answer suggests a different solution. You "accept" the solution that best meets your requirements. The main point is you don't ask a question and forget about it. By accepting an answer we know you have taken the time to read and test the suggested solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the panel is sized to fit the viewport so you will not see the background of the viewport.

You need to implement the `Scrollable` interface of your JPanel to tell the scroll pane you want the panel displayed at its preferred size.

Or, instead of implementing the `Scrollable` interface yourself you can use the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/) which, by default, will display the panel at its preferred size.

Changes to your code would be:

```
ScrollablePanel panel = new ScrollablePanel();
panel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(30, 30) );
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA));
panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
//panel.setLayout(null);
scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
//scrollPane.setViewportView(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView(this);
```

To something like:

```
JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
centerPanel.add(this);
scrollPane.setViewportView(centerPanel);
```

A `GridBagLayout` (by default, unless configured otherwise) will respect the preferred size of the child components and won't stretch them to fill the 'cell'. A scroll pane on the other hand, will stretch the content to (at least) fill the visible area.

Result:

[image]

But seriously, drop the use of `null` layouts. If the effect cannot be achieved using an existing layout (inbuilt or 3rd party) or a combination of layouts, it must have such esoteric positioning constraints that it deserves a custom layout manager.